# apache mod_rewrite: using database to update rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Total newbie at mod_rewrite.

Let's say I want to create nice URLs for every manufacturer on my site,
so I have
www.mysite.com/samsung
www.mysite.com/sony
www.mysite.com/acme

works well enough.

However, if I have hundreds of manufacturers and if they're changing constantly, what then? There are some vague references for something called rewrite map somewhere but nothing that explains it and no tutorials. Can anyone help?

Also, why is this problem not the main topic covered in tutorials for mod_rewrite? How is mod_rewrite possibly useful when you have to maintain it manually (assuming you have new content on your site once in a while)?

There is also mention of needing to have access to httpd.conf
How do I access httpd.conf on my hosting provider's server? How does every other site do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this would typically be done is that you would take all URLs that match a specific pattern and route them to a PHP file (or whatever your server-side programming language is) for more complex routing. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myroute.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then, in your myroute.php file, you can include logic to look at the "url" query string parameter, since it will contain the *original* URL that came in. Perhaps you could match it to a manufacturer in the database, or whatever else is required.

This example obviously takes *all* URLs and maps them to myroute.php. Another example might be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/manufacturers/(.*)$ manuf.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In this case, it will map URLs like so:

> /manufacturers/sony => /manuf.php?name=sony
>   /manufacturers/samsung => /manuf.php?name=samsung
>   etc...

In this case, your manuf.php file could look up the database based on the `name` query string parameter.

Comment: ok, that didn't occur to me... thanks :) but what then? do I route it via header() to the proper URL? how do I keep the pretty URL?

Comment: @A-OK If mod_rewrite can it'll use an "internal" redirect so the user will see see the pre-rewrite "pretty" URL. Examples of where it can't are when the destination is on a separate host or when you explicitly told it to use an HTTP redirect.

Comment: I was asking in relation to the example above. If rewrite redirects all URLs to the myroute.php file which in turn redirects them further via header() (I don't know how else), which URL will be visible once the user arrives at the proper page?

Comment: The myroute.php file can simply `include` the required file for "actual" processing (it doesn't actually do a redirect), once it works out which file is supposed to do the work. If you go with the second `manuf.php` example, then there's no additional redirects anyway, the manuf.php would do all of the work directly.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Unfortunately I can't use that kind of setup for what I intended but I'll use it in the future when doing a site from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this answer while searching for a similar solution — searching a bit further I discovered that mod_rewrite now has the [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html) directive, which will do exactly what you want without the need to run PHP or another scripting language.

It lets you define a mapping rule with a text file, a DBM file, an external script or an SQL query.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Especially this line about [plain text maps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) : Thus, when http://example.com/product/television is requested, the RewriteRule is applied, and the request is internally mapped to http://example.com/prods.php?id=993